# X binary variable and W is dvar float. And i want to have this result if Wi>0 then Xi=1

Tags: cplex, portfolio, opl

With `X` a vector of binary variables, and `W` a vector of float variables, 
I want to write a constraint such that if `W[i] > 0`, then I should have `X[i] = 1`.

```
dvar boolean X[I]; // we choosed stocks i or not
dvar float W[I];    // weight of stocks i in portfolio
```

How can I state this constraint?

Answer (score 1):

You could use logical constraints. Let me give you a small example out of the portfolio example that is in the OPL CPLEX examples.

You may read:

```
dvar float  Allocation[Investments] in FloatRange;  // Investment Level
```

and then you could add:

```
dvar boolean X[Investments];
```

and then in the subject to block you could add:

```
forall(i in Investments) X[i]==(Allocation[i]>=0.001);
```